# SXA on Sitecore 9 shows error "Method not found for Sitecore.Data.ID.Equals()"

Tags: sxa

I installed
Sitecore PowerShell Extensions-4.7 for Sitecore 8 and Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6 rev. 180103 for 9.0 on my Sitecore 9 and I got this error, this installation broke my Sitecore, I already restored and tried 3 times, and the same error pops up

> “Method not found: 'Boolean
>   Sitecore.Data.ID.Equals(Sitecore.Data.ID)'. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Boolean Sitecore.Data.ID.Equals(Sitecore.Data.ID)'.

However, I installed the same items but on Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
And I don´t have this error

Did anyone have a similar situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SXA 1.6 needs Sitecore Experience Platform 8.2 Update 6 or Sitecore 9.0 update 1.
It won't work on Sitecore 9.0 initial release.

For 9.0 initial release, you can use SXA 1.5